# What does "1" mean/represent in MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE?

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm reading Android's [*Camera API documentation*](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) about camera API, this is my first ever use of the API.
 I came accross to some code lines where integers MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE is being invoked, one of them are:

```
      // create a file to save the image
      fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
```

Does this mean like, *1* represents type of file that the camera produces, which is an image ? Or this just represents like *true* for activing the camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1` in this example is a custom value for a variable called `MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE`. It is stored in a variable so that instead of seeing 1's everywhere, you see the name of the variable, which has meaning. 1 has no meaning.

Somewhere in the example it is used to be able to distinguish types

```
if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
    "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
} else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
}
```

Now imagine instead of that, it would say this

```
if (type == 1){
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
    "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
} else if(type == 2) {
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
}
```

that is confusing. Confusing programmers is asking for trouble.

Comment: @Hey-men-whatsup it will do exactly the same, but it's better to use a variable for it. Also read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad

Comment: I see, i missed the second part of your answer. Thank you very much!